# Count number of Exceedence in a series

Tags: c#, linq

I have a series data in `IEnumrable<double>`.

Let the dummy data be:

```
0
0
0
1
1.6
2.5
3.5
2.51
1.0
0
0
0
2.52
3.5
6.5
4.5
1.2
1.0
2.53
3.5
```

let my value of Exceedence be 1.5, so I want to count the number of time my value in series goes above 1.5 (basically number of times 1.5 constant line cut the graph). In above case it will be 3 ({1.6-2.51}, {2.52-4.5}, {2.53-3.5}).

I can do this by iterating through each member and keeping the count everytime it goes up or down the Exceedence value.

I am wondering is there any way to do this using LINQ query.

Comment: This isn't really something that Linq is designed to do as Linq expressions typically act on a single value at a time rather than two sequential values. Iterating is the best way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this answer by Jon Skeet for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619162/linq-list-of-double-values-differences-between-successor-values

Comment: There has to be a way of doing this fairly neatly with a `Sum` (aggregation) - perhaps someone would like to attempt?:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
        bool isAbove = false;
        int count = yourList.Count(x =>
        {
            if (x > 1.5 && !isAbove)
            {
                isAbove = true;
                return true;
            }
            else if (x < 1.5)
            {
                isAbove = false;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: NO this will only return the number of elements that are greater than 1.5. I want the number of block for which value remains greater then 1.5. Let see it this way If i plot a graph for Sine [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sine_and_Cosine.svg) and I draw a line y= 0.5, i want to know how many times line 0.5 cut the sine wave curve

Comment: This doesn't give the correct answer of 3, for the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this helper function that will give you all of the ranges above your limit

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> GetRangesAboveLimit(IEnumerable<double> source, double limit)
{
    //keep going until we've processed the entire range
    while (source.Any())
    {
        //skip elements below the limit
        source = source.SkipWhile(e => e <= limit);
        //yield the elements above the limit
        yield return source.TakeWhile(e => e > limit);
        //now skip those elements and then continue
        source = source.SkipWhile(e => e > limit);
    }
}
```

You'd then be able to use it like this:

```
var range = new double [] { /* initialise here */ };
var rangesAboveLimit = GetRangesAboveLimit(range, 1.5);
```

This would then allow you to not only get the count of how many ranges are above your limit (3) but also allow you to look at the values of those ranges.

The results for your specific example look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun - the same result, using Jon Skeet "SelectPairs" extension method ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619162/linq-list-of-double-values-differences-between-successor-values)):

```
yourList.SelectPairs((x,y) => (x < 1.5 && y > 1.5) ? 1 : 0).Sum()
```

But this doesn't work if there is only one value in the list.

P.S. DoctaJonez answer FTW! :)

Comment: What's FWT? Do you mean FTW? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way of doing it, but it's a sneaky way of doing it with LINQ.

```
float[] numbers = { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 1.6f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 2.51f, 1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 2.52f, 3.5f, 6.5f, 4.5f, 1.2f, 1.0f, 2.53f, 3.5f };

int count = numbers.Where((n, i) => i > 0 && n > 1.5f && numbers[i - 1] < 1.5f).Count();
```